# sfml c++ движение спрайта определенное время

Tags: c++, sfml

у меня такой вопрос.Начал писать игрушку для изучения SFML.
Как сделать так что бы спрайт двигался вверх и вниз плавно.Тоесть 2 секунды он двигается вверх,а 2 вниз. Пытался сделать это с переменными,накопал информацию про clock,но как именно его использовать с .move я не понял.  Вот кусок кода

````
       {
      
           playersprite.move(0, -0.05);
           if (i=2)
           {
               

           }
           i++;
       }
       else
       {
           playersprite.move(0, 0.05);
           i=i-1;
       }```
````

Comment: Вам нужно знать расстояние на которое он должен переместиться за эти 2 секунды, поделить его на время, и переместить на дельту от времени. А так же `(i=2)` это присваивается цифра 2 в переменную а не сравнивается. почитайте информация как раз для вас, ответ я не могу написать http://c2community.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=73634

Comment: Я незнаю как именно сделать так чтоб двигался он определенное время. расстояние 13 пикселей по игрику.